# On first click do first function, Other clicks do other function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that switches images src on click but, I need to make sure they cant click the same photo multiple times in a row so the 1 of the images doesnt get lost. Plus some other things need to happen there in the future.

Now the problem is i'm trying my best to make this happen but still cant figure it out. Somehow it stays in the first `if`

**Here is my code:**

```
var countSwitch = 0;
if(countSwitch == 0){
    $('.display-img').click(function(){
        countSwitch++;

        selectImg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $(this).addClass('last-clicked');

        currentImg = $('.prime-img img').attr('src');

        $(this).find('img').attr('src', currentImg);

        $('.prime-img img').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $('.prime-img img').attr('src', selectImg);
        }).fadeIn(400); 
        console.log('eerste count', countSwitch);
        console.log('eerste');
    });
}
if(countSwitch >= 0){
    $('.display-img').click(function(){
        $('figure').removeClass('last-clicked');
        $(this).addClass('last-clicked');

        selectImg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        currentImg = $('.prime-img img').attr('src');

        $(this).find('img').attr('src', currentImg);

        $('.prime-img img').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $('.prime-img img').attr('src', selectImg);
        }).fadeIn(400); 
        console.log('2e');
        console.log('2e count', countSwitch);

    });
}
```

Comment: You need to check the condition within the click handler

Comment: It should be greater than symbol instead of less than symbol.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks this was the fix! If you want me to confirm your answer post it as one :-D

Comment: @J.Dekkers can you share your html sample also.. looks like the script can be simplified a bit more

Comment: also what is the difference between both these calls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your countSwitch variable if statement inside click event:

```
var countSwitch = 0;

$('.display-img').click(function(){

    if(countSwitch == 0) {
        countSwitch++;
        selectImg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $(this).addClass('last-clicked');

        currentImg = $('.prime-img img').attr('src');

        $(this).find('img').attr('src', currentImg);

        $('.prime-img img').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $('.prime-img img').attr('src', selectImg);
        }).fadeIn(400); 
        console.log('eerste count', countSwitch);
        console.log('eerste');
    } else {
        $('figure').removeClass('last-clicked');
        $(this).addClass('last-clicked');

        selectImg = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        currentImg = $('.prime-img img').attr('src');

        $(this).find('img').attr('src', currentImg);

        $('.prime-img img').fadeOut(400, function() {
            $('.prime-img img').attr('src', selectImg);
        }).fadeIn(400); 
        console.log('2e');
        console.log('2e count', countSwitch);
    }
});
```

Comment: Another way could be that the first click removes the event and add the next event, but it gets harder than just your if. +1

Comment: This would never work, because you up the countSwitch to 1 right before you check if the value is equal to 0, which it would never be.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a condition check, use a cleaner approach by using [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
$('.display-img').one( "click", function(){

  //first function call

  //now bind the second click handler
    $('.display-img').bind( "click", function(){
       //second function call
    } );

} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation runs once, evaluates (countSwitch == 0) as true, then adds one (the first) event handler that will always be executed.

Depending on the exact behavior you're trying to achieve, you can either:

1. Follow gurvinder372's advice and use .one() and .bind(), if your first function should only run once per image.
2. Use OscarJ's implementation, which adds one .click() event handler and uses countSwitch's value to determine what code to execute. I believe this is what you were trying to achieve.
3. Finally, since you mentioned not wanting to lose data, you can also use HTML5's data attributes to store your initial image path. If each image needs to change to a different image, you can also store your new image's path here. The attributes will always stay, so you don't risk losing anything while manipulating your element.

For HTML5 data attributes, I recommend reading [MDN's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes). jQuery's [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/) also uses these attributes to get their value.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are evaluated when you attach the event. You need to instead have them evaluated when the event is triggered.

I think this might work:

```
var countSwitch = 0;
$('.display-img').click(function(){
    if(countSwitch == 0){
        countSwitch++;
        // handle first click
    } else {
        // handle further clicks
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As Arun said, you need to check the condition within the click-handler. As you wrote your function, the second handler would never be initialized. I simplified your code, and made an example of a way you could do this:

```
var countSwitch = 0;

$('.click-handler').click(function(){

  if(countSwitch === 0) {
    firstFunction();
  } else {
    secondFunction();
  }

  countSwitch++;

});


function firstFunction() {  
  console.log('First count', countSwitch);
}

function secondFunction() {
  console.log('Second count', countSwitch);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/tuponisado/edit?js,console,output